# Fliter results of gci with strings from a textfile in Powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

After having ripped all my mother's DVD library to a Drobo-FS I setup for her, she was faced with the problem that having so many choices just a mouse-click away from made it too hard to choose. My solution was a Powershell script that starts playing a random movie:

```
$files = Get-Childitem -Recurse -Path "\\DROBO-FS\Videos\Movies" -include *.mkv,*.avi,*.mp4,*.m4v
$ran = Get-Random -minimum 0 -maximum ($files.length - 1)
$movie = $files[$ran] 
& "C:\Program Files (x86)\MPC-HC\mpc-hc.exe" $movie
```

The problem now is that there are a few movies in there she doesn't want to show up randomly, things she only watches on certain occasions or simply doesn't like.

My solution to this would be a text file into which she could write the names of the movies she doesn't want as part of the random choices. My problem is that I am not quite sure how to read in the names in the text file and then filter them out of the results gotten from Get-Childitem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the file names of the movies you want to exclude in a file (one name.ext per line) and pass the content of the file to the Exclude parameter:

```
$exclude = Get-Content .\exclude.txt
$files = Get-Childitem -Recurse -Path "\\DROBO-FS\Videos\Movies" -Include *.mkv,*.avi,*.mp4,*.m4v -Exclude $exclude
$movie = $files | Get-Random
& "C:\Program Files (x86)\MPC-HC\mpc-hc.exe" $movie.FullName
```